# finding shorted path to a position using python

Tags: python

> Guys this is a question i got part of google foobar challege
> You have maps of parts of the space station, each starting at a prison
> exit and ending at the door to an escape pod. The map is represented
> as a matrix of 0s and 1s, where 0s are passable space and 1s are
> impassable walls. The door out of the prison is at the top left
> (0,0)(0,0) and the door into an escape pod is at the bottom right
> (w−1,h−1)(w−1,h−1).
>
> Write a function answer(map) that generates the length of the shortest
> path from the prison door to the escape pod, where you are allowed to
> remove one wall as part of your remodeling plans. The path length is
> the total number of nodes you pass through, counting both the entrance
> and exit nodes. The starting and ending positions are always passable
> (0). The map will always be solvable, though you may or may not need
> to remove a wall. The height and width of the map can be from 2 to 20.
> Moves can only be made in cardinal directions; no diagonal moves are
> allowed.
>
> Test cases
>
> Input:
>
> maze = [[0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0]]
> Output:
>
> 7 Input:
>
> maze = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
> [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]] Output:
>
> 11
> and this is its answer i got online

```
from collections import deque

class Node:

    def __init__(self, x, y, saldo, grid):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y;
        self.saldo = saldo
        self.grid = grid

    def __hash__(self):
        return self.x ^ self.y

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y and self.saldo == other.saldo

    def get_neighbors(self):
        neighbors = []
        x = self.x
        y = self.y
        saldo = self.saldo
        grid = self.grid
        rows = len(grid)
        columns = len(grid[0])

        if x > 0:
            wall = grid[y][x - 1] == 1
            if wall:
                if saldo > 0:
                    neighbors.append(Node(x - 1, y, saldo - 1, grid))
            else:
                neighbors.append(Node(x - 1, y, saldo, grid))

        if x < columns - 1:
            wall = grid[y][x + 1] == 1
            if wall:
                if saldo > 0:
                    neighbors.append(Node(x + 1, y, saldo - 1, grid))
            else:
                neighbors.append(Node(x + 1, y, saldo, grid))

        if y > 0:
            wall = grid[y - 1][x] == 1
            if wall:
                if saldo > 0:
                    neighbors.append(Node(x, y - 1, saldo - 1, grid))
            else:
                neighbors.append(Node(x, y - 1, saldo, grid))

        if y < rows - 1:
            wall = grid[y + 1][x]
            if wall:
                if saldo > 0:
                    neighbors.append(Node(x, y + 1, saldo - 1, grid))
            else:
                neighbors.append(Node(x, y + 1, saldo, grid))

        return neighbors

def answer(maze):
    rows = len(maze)
    columns = len(maze[0])
    
    source = Node(0, 0, 1, maze)
    queue = deque([source])
    distance_map = {source: 1}
    
    while queue:
        current_node = queue.popleft()

        if current_node.x == columns - 1 and\
            current_node.y == rows - 1:
            return distance_map[current_node]

        for child_node in current_node.get_neighbors():
            if child_node not in distance_map.keys():
                distance_map[child_node] = distance_map[current_node] + 1
                queue.append(child_node)
```

> and this description was there along with solution Basically you need
> a breadth-first search with a minor tweak:
>
> each node represents a cell in the grid (x- and y-coordinates), each
> node knows its "saldo" (how many walls it may penetrate). What comes
> to that saldo, if a node has zero saldo, it may not generate those its
> neighbors that are occupied by wall. If saldo is s>0s>0, and the node
> has a wall neighbor node uu, uu is generated with saldo s−1s−1.
>
> The rest is breadth-first search: as soon you remove the exit node
> from the queue, just print its distance from the starting node:
>
> ## But even after a long effort i am unable to understand what "saldo"
>
> ## means here and how it affects the result

i did not undertand the logic of its use

Comment: *"saldo" (how many walls it may penetrate)*

Comment: i did not undertand the logic of its use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> you are allowed to remove one wall as part of your remodeling plans.

Apparently, the variable `saldo` represents the number of walls you can remove during your escape.
It is decremented when you remove a wall; tests are made to assert whether you are still allowed to remove a wall.

Comment: can you please tell me the logic behind these steps

        if x > 0:
            wall = grid[y][x - 1] == 1
            if wall:
                if saldo > 0:
                    neighbors.append(Node(x - 1, y, saldo - 1, grid))
            else:
                neighbors.append(Node(x - 1, y, saldo, grid))

Comment: because it checking location [y][x-1] and act on location [x-1][y]
@Reblochon Masque

Comment: I think it checks if the cell has a neighbor at `x-1`; if it has, it checks if there is a wall there; if there is a wall, it checks if it can remove it, and decrements `saido`, etc... 
It is exploring the space, while trying to remove walls when it can.

Comment: but it is adding another location to the list of neighbors why that?
if that wall removed its should be added right?

Comment: I think it is not. the addressing of the grid seems to be in reverse order than the parameters `x` and `y` of the Node construction. I would suggest to rename `x` and `y` with 'row` and `col` to verify that, and clarify the code.